# Google Cloud Build failed for Laravel artisan, involving database connection

Tags: build, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to pack source as image and build by Google Cloud Build

here's my docker file:

```
FROM php
RUN cd ~ && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN cd ~ && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
ADD ./mysource /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN cd /app && composer update --ignore-platform-reqs && composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN cd /app && composer require laravel/horizon && php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Horizon\HorizonServiceProvider"
```

turned out the build failed and log showed:
(newest log at the top)

```
Step #1: 
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
Finished Step #1
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c cd /app && composer update --ignore-platform-reqs && composer install --ignore-platform-reqs' returned a non-zero code: 1
Step #1: Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
Step #1: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused 
Step #1: In PDOConnection.php line 46:
Step #1: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused 
Step #1: In PDOConnection.php line 50:
Step #1: chema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = explorers) 
Step #1: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_s 
Step #1: 
Step #1: In Connection.php line 664:
Step #1: 
Step #1: > @php artisan package:discover
Step #1: > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Step #1: Generating optimized autoload files
```

I'm looking for something like [services in bitbucket pipeline](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-services-and-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-874786688.html), which u could use during build process . I also referenced the issue raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127983/laravel-project-gcloud-app-deploy-failed), but those responds didn't resolve my situation.

appreciate for any idea

Comment: How do your laravel-project/.env settings look like? It may be worthwhile checking and updating these settings with the correct database connection parameters. 

Are there any user name and password configured in the laradock/.env file?

Comment: yes the .env is well config, and I'm pretty sure that's something with connection betweens 'steps' if cloud build. Coz I did also try connecting to previous step by the most simple mysql cli, to localhost/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/<container name of previous step> all failed

Comment: More detail on my cloud build yaml
Step1:gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
arg: run --name=mysql -p 3306:3306 --env MYSQL_USER=forge --env MYSQL_PASSWORD=forge --env MYSQL_DATABASE=forge --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret --env MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -d circleci/mysql


Step2:gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
arg:build -t <..... build an img from a dockerfile>

Having connection attempt in docker file like 
RUN mysql -u root --password=root -h 127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --database=forge

Comment: Are connection parameters correct? You need to adjust them manually, to facilitate build success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to post an update for my solution.
I turned out adding a MySQL container with **creating a specific network and have the  name specified in all other steps(containers)** `--network <network_name>` , so the containers in following steps could directly connect by the name of the mysql container.

To play safe I added a container as a buffer to ensure that mysql container has sufficient time to be build and up.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['network','create','gcb_network']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['run','--name=mysql','-p','3306:3306','--network','gcb_network','--env','MYSQL_USER=<user>','--env','MYSQL_PASSWORD=<pwd>','--env','MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<user>','--env','MYSQL_DATABASE=<dbname>','-d','mysql/mysql-server:5.7']
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['sleep','10']
  id: 'MYSQLDeferrer'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/<projectname>/<img_name>:latest','--network','gcb_network','-f','<path_to_docker_file>','.']
  waitFor:
    - 'MYSQLDeferrer'
  env:
  - 'DB_HOST='
  - 'DB_USERNAME='
  - 'DB_PASSWORD='
images: ['gcr.io/<projectname>/<img_name>']
```

you may/may not need the env according to ur setting.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/351#issuecomment-370056462,

> Unfortunately, during the build phase, the CloudSQL connection is not available.